# How to show that $0<b'<b$?

Tags: inequality

> If $a, b, q$ are natural numbers with $\frac{1}{q + 1} < \frac ba < \frac1q$, show that
>   $$
> \frac{b}{a} - \frac{1}{q+1} = \frac{b'}{a(q+1)}
> $$
>   where $0<b'<b$.

I did the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {\frac{1}{q+1}}&<&{\quad \quad  \frac{b}{a}}&<&{\quad \,\,\frac{1}{q}}  \\ 
  {}& &{}& &{} \\
  {0\quad }&<&{\frac{b(q+1)-a}{a(q+1)}}&<&{\frac{1}{q(q+1)}}  \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So I guess that $b'=b(q+1)-a$. Now I have to show that $0 < b'<b$, but I don't know what else to do. I tried to do this:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {b(q+1)-a}&<&{b} \\ 
  {bq+b-a-b}&<&{0} \\ 
  {bq-a}&<&{0} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

But it seems to take me nowhere.

Comment: You are done! $\frac{b}{a} < \frac{1}{q}$ $\implies$ $bq < a$ This is true since all numbers are positive

Comment: @rightskewed Yes! The condition of comparability of rational numbers. I had this insight yesterday but used in a cumbersome way that yielded nothing. Now I forgot to use it. Thanks!

Comment: You did it but you are not seeing it